# Is it possible to put javascript inside Switch Case PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having problems putting javascript inside the PHP switch case, I get this problem:

## Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) or '}' in

Here is the code:

```
case 'settings':
        <script type="text/javascript">
            ($('<div class="'+ currentdiv +'">').load(settings.php).appendTo
            ($(targetdiv)));
        </script>
      break;
```

Comment: You need to echo it as a string.

Comment: wrap it as a heredoc. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: You cannot put JS into PHP like this. You gotta either print (echo) it, or close the PHP tag and then reopen it when needed/after you're finished with the JS chunk.

Comment: Thank you very much friends, but the problem was opening and closing php for javascript output https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101489/7560197

Comment: @miken32 I'm sorry, I did not find this question, and even if I thought I would not know the answer, because I thought I could not leave javascript in switch case!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! The problem was in closing the php and opening it again as it could not leave the javascript inside php!

```
case 'configurations':
       ?> <script type="text/javascript">
            ($('<div class="div-content">').load("server/settings.php").appendTo
            (".content-loaded-tab"));
        </script>
    <?php
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to capture it as String and then echo it to the document.

```
case 'settings':
  $script = "<script type='text/javascript'>\r\n";
  $script .= '\t$("<div>", { class: currentdiv }).load("settings.php").appendTo($(targetdiv)));\r\n';
  $script .= "</script>\r\n";
  echo $script;
  break;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy, but the problem was opening and closing php for javascript output https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101489/7560197

Comment: @WillJohn yes you can escape PHP or capture it as a String. Either way.

Comment: I would suggest not appending html into a variable whenever possible, especially using concatenation on every line. It's clunky, slower and forces you to escape double quotes (unless you use heredoc syntax). (Additionally, some IDEs might not even recognize it as HTML at all)

Comment: @Jeto I subscribe to keeping each separated, using templates, heredoc etc. OP didn't appear to be using this, so I provided an answer for that specific use case.

Comment: @Twisty Fair enough!